# How to apply Android R8 obfuscation to native code?

Tags: android, c++, gradle, java-native-interface, proguard

I'm developing an Android app that has to be obfuscated for security reasons. Some classes and fields that are obfuscated by R8 are used in my C++ code, so of course the obfuscation step breaks this part of the code.

My question is, since I don't want to just keep those classes and fields unobfuscated, how can I script an automatic modification of the C++ code based on the `mapping.txt` that is output by R8?

More specifically, the issues I'm facing while trying to tackle this problem are the following:

- How should I go about editing the source code just for the compilation without permanently modifying it in my project
- I believe the native part gets compiled first, prior to the compilation of the Kotlin part and then prior to the generation of the `mapping.txt` file, so how can I reorder the tasks or work around this problem

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The typical approach **is** to keep "those classes and fields unobfuscated".

Comment: Is there no atypical approach to this according to you? Or is it just highly discouraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the spark of an idea, up to you to see if it is workable:

1. Take the `mapping.txt` of a build and remove everything except the parts needed by your JNI code.
2. Pass that file to R8 with the `-applymapping` option in all subsequent builds. This will keep the JNI symbols obfuscated but stable. Other symbols will still be randomly obfuscated.
3. Use mapping.txt as source for the `m` table in the following function:

```
inline constexpr const char * mapping(const char* in) {
    std::pair<const char *, const char *> m[] = {
        {"important/class","a"},
        {"important/other/class", "a.b"},
    };
    for (const auto& [normal, obfuscated]: m) {
        if (!strcmp(normal, in)) return obfuscated;
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

4. Now use `mapping("foo")` anywhere you need to reference a class, field or type name.

In a [brief experiment](https://godbolt.org/z/n5oqz8bjf) the compiler completely inlined and eliminated the `mapping` function, leaving only the obfuscated type in place.

Comment: Thank you for the idea and detailed answer. I had not thought of that exact approach and I like it. I did think about manually obfuscating beforehand but did not quite figure out a way to do it neatly. That just might be the way to go about it :) I'm gonna look into it.

Comment: By any chance, do you know how I'm supposed to specify to include my custom `mapping.txt` file along with the `consumer-rules.pro` that uses it? I didn't mention that it's an Android library that I'm developing. I've tried adding `consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro", "custom-mapping.txt"` in my `build.gradle` but it seems to be interpreted as a second Proguard rules file by the consumer app (I'm getting an error "Expected char '-' at .../proguard.txt:1:1")

Comment: I think you have to add `-applymapping path/to/mapping.txt` to your proguard configuration file.

Comment: I did, but since I have an app depending on my Android library module, I assume I should perform the `-applymapping` it in the `consumer-rules.pro` file as well, and have a way to pass the mapping file to the consumer.

Comment: I was confused, but it actually shouldn't be in the `consumer-rules.pro` in my case since I didn't want external apps to have access to the original names. But I did reference the mapping in my internal app that depends on my library. I've simply placed the mapping file in a directory common to the library and the app, and put `-applymapping` in both `proguard-rules.pro`. What I'll have to do in the `consumer-rules.pro` though is configure keep rules for those obfuscated names that shouldn't be changed by consumers, it would break the lib otherwise.